# How to display the custom post related blog by category?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, posts

I am using WordPress and I have to show the related blog by category. I have created a custom-type post. I tried the below code but the code is displaying the last category of the post.

Would you help me out with this issue?

```
function relatedBlogPost($atts){
global $post;
$custom_terms = get_terms('blogs_cat');
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'blog',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug
            ),
        ),
        'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
        //'order' => 'DEC'
     );

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
$data='';
$data .= '<ul>';
while($loop->have_posts()){
      $loop->the_post();
/*get category name*/
$terms = get_the_terms( $loop->ID , 'blogs_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$catname=$term->name;
}
  $data.= '<li> <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
                <div class="main-blogBoxwrapper">
                <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().'">
                <div class="blogCatname">
                <h6><span>'.$catname.'</span></h6>
                <h4>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 14, '...').'</h4>
                <p>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 20, '...').'</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a></li>';
   }
    $data.='</ul>';
    return $data;
wp_reset_postdata();

}
}

}
add_shortcode( 'related-blog-post', 'relatedBlogPost');
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know below code is the best code but it's solved my issues

```
function relatedBlogPost($atts){

        global $post;
       //this the the custom post type 
    
        $args_cat = array( 
            'taxonomy'     => 'blogs_cat',
            'orderby'      => 'name',
            'show_count'   => 1,
            'pad_counts'   => 1, 
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'echo'         => 0
        );
        $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, "blogs_cat"); // getting the category id of the current post
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'blog',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $categories[0]->slug // sending the current category slug name
                    ),
                ),
                'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
                'order' => 'DEC'
            );
        
        $related = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $related->have_posts() ) { 
            $data='<h2 class="sectionHeading pb-5">Related Blog</h2>';
            $data .= '<div class="main-Blog"><ul>';
            while( $related->have_posts() ) { 
                $related->the_post(); 
                //displaying the category name
        $terms = get_the_terms( $related->ID , 'blogs_cat' );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $catname=$term->name;
        }
                
     $data.= '<li> <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
                            <div class="main-blogBoxwrapper">
                            <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().'">
                            <div class="blogCatname">
                            <h6><span>'.$catname.'</span></h6>
                            <h4>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 14, '...').'</h4>
                            <p>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 20, '...').'</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </a></li>';
            }
            $data.='</ul></div>';
            return $data;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        
        }
        add_shortcode( 'related-blog-post', 'relatedBlogPost');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do this way, category specific topics will be listed put it on the page and try

```
query_posts('category_name=product');
```